# Use Service or Binder object to set variable inside Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-binder

I can either set an variable int[] by using the binder object or using the service class object itself. Code is in `public class MyActivity extends Activity.` Which one is the way to go, both works:

```
    private BackgroundService.BackgroundBinder mBoundBinder; // to get methods of nested binder class inside BackgroundService
    private BackgroundService mBoundService; //service class object

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        mBoundService = ((BackgroundService.BackgroundBinder) binder).getService(); //google version
        mBoundBinder = ((BackgroundService.BackgroundBinder) binder);
    }
```

Service int[] array can be set in two ways:

```
1. mBoundService.setListeners = genArr(); //genArr() returns int[]
2. mBoundBinder.setListeners(genArr());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [android.developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) version uses following inside Service class. This shrinks the necessary `nested Binder class` down to one method returning the service object itself, thus its methods can directly be accessed. Nice.

```
  public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return LocalService.this;
    }
  }
```